# How one should use jenkinsci/jnlp-slave for complex builds?

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ecs

I am struggling with jenkinsci/jnlp-slave docker image and ECS Plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Container+Service+Plugin

I am using complex docker containers (based on CentOS) for the builds. 
It works perfectly on local docker, but I want to try ECS and plugin above.

If I add **"FROM jenkinsci/jnlp-slave"** at the end of my big Dockerfile, it breaks the whole environment, nothing works (no yum, no gcc, no npm etc)

It doesn't work at the beginning of the Dockerfile either.

```
FROM jenkinsci/jnlp-slave

FROM centos:6.8

[...]
```

It this case the master doesn't connect to the slave.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Just added the following lines at the end of my huge Dockerfile:

```
COPY /files/slave.jar /tmp/slave.jar
COPY /files/jenkins-slave /usr/local/bin/jenkins-slave
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/jenkins-slave
USER jenkins
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/jenkins-slave"]
```

(obviously `slave.jar` and `jenkins-slave` must be present in the `files` folder)

jenkins-slave can be retrieved [from this project](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-jnlp-slave)